# Understanding In App Purchases

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

Our app has in app purchase feature.  Targer OS is iOS and android both.
I wanted to know that can the user buy the products listed in app purchases from our app website. Edit: products to ultimately utilised inside app even if purchsing from app website ( product similar like say a power of a game level/or virtual currency)

I have searched on the net and apple documentation says that:
Selling outside is permitted but value should not be less than listed in the in app purchase and no link to outside should be visible in thd app for purchase.

Is it true?
But I was not able to find much about android.

Do anyone of you have experience in this?

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

From https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html

> In-app purchases: Developers offering virtual goods or currencies
>   within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's
>   in-app billing service as the method of payment. Developers offering
>   additional content, services or functionality within another category
>   of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app
>   billing service as the method of payment, except: where payment is
>   primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets,
>   or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy
>   subscription); or where payment is for digital content or goods that
>   may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can
>   be played on other music players).

Comment: I have made edit in the question:Edit: products to ultimately utilised inside app even if purchsing from app website ( product similar like say a power of a game level/ or like virtual currency)

Comment: Unless the in-app purchase can somehow be consumed outside of your app (like e.g. a journal article) I don't think you are allowed to sell it outside of your Android app. But I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. If you want to have definite answer consult a lawyer.